# Cytoscape : multiple instances and no graph display

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to display several instances of cytoscape in a single page, in a time sequence: first one set of nodes are displayed on the graph, the user must interact with it (create edges), then he moves to a second graph (#cy0 is :hidden and #cy1 is :visible).

For code optimisation sake I wish to use the same initialisation function to display different successive sets of nodes. My initialisation function works fine in the first instance, but the graph is not created (cy.initrender() == false) in the second session. A command is probably missing, I tested a couple, but I don't see what to do.

Here is my code:

//elements

```
$(function(){ // on dom ready
var elesJson = {
nodes: [
  { data: { id: 'S', faveShape: 'rectangle',} }
   ...
  ],

edges: [
    { data: { id: 'loan', source: 'B', target: 'U' } },
    ...
        ],
```

};

// instance index
    var indexLevel=0;

// cy initialisation

```
$("#cy"+indexLevel).cytoscape({

style: cytoscape.stylesheet()...

elements: elesJson, 
ready: function(){
    window.cy = this;});
```

// jQuery command to move from one instance to the other.

```
$('#next').click(function(){
$("#cy"+indexLevel).css("visibility","hidden");
indexLevel++;
$("#cy"+indexLevel).css("visibility","visible");
cy.load(elesJson);
cy.ready(); 
console.log(cy.initrender());
});
```

I am able to generate my node.collection, it is not empty, but the canvas element is not created and/or displayed within the #cy div, and cy.initrender() returns "false".

Any solution to this?

Comment: Well, I've found the answer: load the successive graphs in a single #cy div...

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the docs for init, you must call `cy.resize()` if you play around with the cy div's `display` or `position`: http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/initialisation

`cy.resize()` : http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize

Edit: You may want to use `z-index` instead to simplify things...